# How to Assign value based on the Parent Field in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have one table in `SQL` and I want to update the `OrderNo` column which is presently `null`. I want to get that updated from `0,1,2,3,4,5...` based on the parent `questionId`.

The table looks like this:

```
Id  ParentId    OrderNo
1   1           NULL
2   1           NULL
3   1           NULL
4   2           NULL
5   2           NULL
6   3           NULL
7   3           NULL
8   3           NULL
9   3           NULL
```

I want that based on the `ParentId`, it should update the `OrderNo` column.

e.g `ParentId 1` => then order no should be from `0,1,2`.

I tried to work with cursor and other `CTE` queries but didn't found any best approach for this.

Desired output:

```
Id  ParentId    OrderNo
1   1           0
2   1           1
3   1           2
4   2           0
5   2           1
6   3           0
7   3           1
8   3           2
9   3           3
```

Comment: Please mention your desired output along with what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can do this with `window function` and `common table expression`:

```
;with cte as(select *, -1 + row_number() over(partition by parentid 
                                              order by id) as rn from tablename)
update cte set orderno = rn
```